# What does the hyphen "-" mean in "tar xzf -"?

Tags: command-line, tar

When try to install dropbox from command  line, I read the commands

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

what does  `-` mean here? is it previous directory?

Comment: A bit of pedantry: the option you're asking about is `f -`. This might make finding the answer in the man pages a little easier.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could explain what, *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation of `wget` and `tar`. That way, the respective developers can improve their documentation so that future users don't stumble over the same problems again. In other words: be a hero and make the world a better place!

Comment: It would be a nice default for tar to use stdin, but since it’s heritage is to work with tapes it did not do that. Instead it learned how to work with files (with the f option) and then follows the convention to have a - in place of the filename for stdin (In case of eXtract or stdout in case of Create)

Comment: @eckes In the case of GNU tar, stdin *is* the default unless `$TAPE` is set.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Some commands accept `-` in place of a filename, either:

- To write to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) instead of to a named file. This is what the `-` argument passed to `wget` after `-O` is doing.
- To read from [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) instead of from a named file. This is what the `-` argument passed to `tar` after `xzf`.

The command you showed downloads an archive file with `wget` and unpacks it with `tar`. To achieve this, the output of `wget` is [piped](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) (`|`) to the input of `tar`. This is why `wget` writes to standard output instead of a file and `tar` reads from standard input instead of a file.

Comment: I'd say "most commands" rather than just "some commands". I believe it's part of the POSIX option syntax specification.

Comment: @Barmar Yes and no: [Guideline 13:
For utilities that use operands to represent files to be opened for either reading or writing, the '-' operand should be used to mean only standard input (or standard output when it is clear from context that an output file is being specified) **or a file named `-`.**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html). So **if** `-` is an operand for a "file option" *and* it has a special meaning, *then* it must be that of stdin/stdout. The program is free to not treat as a special case and simply look for file `-`

Comment: (and typically in those cases omitting the option will be the same as using `-`)

Comment: @Bakuriu I don't see how that refutes what I said. I suspect most commands take filename arguments, so they're supposed to follow that guideline. But maybe I should have qualified it as "most commands that operate on files".

Comment: @Barmar One way to follow the guideline is to *decline* to treat `-` specially at all, treating it as a literal filename. The only way to go against the guideline is to treat `-` specially but with some other meaning than the ones the guideline suggests.

Comment: @Barmar Your comment can be misinterpreted to read that all POSIX commands interpret `-` like that, so only the few that are not POSIX do not, while the correct interpretation is that among all POSIX commands, most implement this convention and the rest treat `-` to simply mean "file named `-`" and don't have other conventions. I wanted to clarify that ambiguity

Comment: @EliahKagan The only point I was trying to make was that this isn;t something that a few commands implement, it's widespread convention that's recommended by the specification.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that `f -` is redundant with `tar`, although I certainly type the magic spell `xvpf` without actually thinking.

Answer (score 12):

That's just a filename that a lot of Unix programs interpret as "instead of actually opening a file, read from `stdin` (or write to `stdout`)."

That means reading from the input that gets streamed into the program; in your case, that's the output of wget.

Comment: Is it really a *filename*, though?

Comment: @EricDuminil It's a filename in the sense that programs accept it in some places where they would otherwise only accept filenames, but you're right that it's not really about an actual name of a file in some directory.

Comment: @EricDuminil: In particular, for programs that follow this convention, you have to use `./-` if you *actually* want to open a file named `-`.

Comment: @EricDuminil In fact: yes! It *names* a *file*; in the unix sense, `stdin` is a file descriptor, and `-` is the name you supply to use that. It's not a file name from the OS's perspective, though. Only from the user perspective.

Comment: @EricDuminil No, it is not a filename. Their respecitve filenames are `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout`. These files are opened by default when starting a process, so no need to open them once more.

Comment: @rexkogitans no. `/dev/stdin` is just a convenience file name offered by some kernel facility. There's usually **no** `fopen("/dev/stdin", "r")` happening anywhere when you write a program that chooses to use stdin; you just go ahead and use the `extern FILE* stdin` that your libc header provided you with; by the way, that is the integer file descriptor `0`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's exactly what I wrote. The file is opened on process start, and FILE* stdin is a handle to this opened file. `man 3 stdin` tells you that _Under normal circumstances every UNIX program has three streams opened for it when it starts up, one for input, one for output, and one for printing diagnostic or error messages._

Comment: no, it's not "opened" at start. It's simply there. There's no `fopen` happening anywhere.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The discussion runs into a wrong direction. The point is, that device files called `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` exist, whilst there is no file named `-`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller *no, it's not "opened" at start. It's simply there. There's no `fopen` happening anywhere.*  Pedantically, it would be an `fdopen()` (or equivalent) since only the raw POSIX-style file descriptor and not the standard C `FILE *` is inherited by a child process. Wrapping that POSIX file descriptor in a `FILE *` stream has to happen some time after the new process is `exec`'d and before `main()` is called.

Answer (score 5):

The `-` argument to `tar` specifies that the archive should be read from `stdin` instead of a file. From the [GNU tar manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/file.html#SEC106):

> If you use `-` as an *archive-name*, `tar` reads the archive from standard input (when listing or extracting files)

Other commands have the same behavior, and it is specified by the [POSIX.1-2017 standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html):

> **Guideline 13**:
>
> For utilities that use operands to represent files to be opened for either reading or writing, the '`-`' operand should be used to mean
>   only standard input (or standard output when it is clear from context
>   that an output file is being specified) or a file named `-`.