# What is the difference between cat and tee?

Tags: command-line, apache2, php, email

I was playing around with the Apache `php.ini` and got it so when I send emails with a PHP file that has the `mail()` function it will save the email on my computer, which is good for testing and for web developers. This is the line of code I added in the `php.ini`:

```
sendmail_path = "cat > /home/cam/Documents/TestEmails/`date '+%Y-%m-%d - %H-%M-%S'`.eml"
```

Also this line of code worked too:

```
sendmail_path = "tee > /home/cam/Documents/TestEmails/`date '+%Y-%m-%d - %H-%M-%S'`.eml"
```

What are the difference between the `cat` and `tee` commands?

Answer (score 13):

> **TL;DR:** `cat` reads from files whose names you pass it, but `tee` writes to them. Only when you pass no filenames to them do they have the same effect. Otherwise, using `tee` when you mean `cat` can overwrite files you meant to read, causing accidental data loss.

`cat` and `tee` behave alike when you don't give them any filenames. That's what's happening in your example; the commands have [output redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output) (`>`) but no actual command-line arguments. When you do pass the `cat` and `tee` commands filenames, they behave differently from one another, and you can even accidentally overwrite files and lose data by passing their names to `tee` when you meant to pass them to `cat`.

The reason `cat` and `tee` do the same thing without any arguments, but different things with filenames passed as arguments, can be discerned by considering the behavior of each. In general, they have almost opposite behavior. `cat` reads potentially many files and sends their output to one place, while `tee` reads one input and sends it to potentially many files.

### [cat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cat.1.html)

`cat` copies the content of all its input files to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)), one after the other. This is to say that it concatenates the files. For example, `cat x y` outputs the contents of `x` followed by the contents of `y`. When passed a single filename, it copies that file's contents to standard output and then, since it has no more arguments, stops.

When you run `cat` with *no* filenames, it defaults to reading from its own [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)). Basically, that means it reads whatever is [piped](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) or [redirected](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) to it, or otherwise whatever is typed into a terminal. (Another way of putting this is that, with no filenames, `cat` behaves like `cat -`, since `cat`, [like various other commands](https://askubuntu.com/a/1151912/22949), treats `-` specially and takes it to designate standard input.)

### [tee](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/tee.1.html)

`tee` copies the content of its standard input to all of its output files *as well as its own standard output*. This is to say that it functions like a [T-junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_junction)--or, more precisely, *N* T-junctions where *N* is the number of output files whose names you pass to it. For example, `tee x` reads its input, writes it to the file `x`, and also writes it to its own standard output. `tee x y` reads its input, writes it to the file `x` and *also* to the file `y`, and also writes it to its own standard output.

The most common use of `tee` is to insert it into a pipeline with a single filename argument. For example, suppose you were piping the output of a command called `foo` to the input of a command called `bar`. You could write `foo | bar`. But if you also wanted to log the output to a file called `logfile` so you could inspect it, you could use `foo | tee logfile | bar`.

`tee` overwrites the files whose names you give it, unless you pass it the `-a` option, in which case it appends to them. For example, to append to that log instead of overwriting it, you could use `foo | tee -a logfile | bar`.

Unlike `cat`, the `tee` command doesn't treat getting no filename arguments as a special case. Instead, simply writes its input to *all zero* of the files whose names you gave it, and then passes it along to its standard output as usual. The effect is that, as with `cat`, running `tee` with no filenames also copies standard input to standard output.

### Culture favors cat when you just want to copy stdin to stdout.

While you can use either `cat` or `tee` with no arguments for this purpose, if you use `cat` then people will know what you mean. `tee` without arguments is fine, but it *looks* like a mistake. Sometimes this is described by saying that `cat` is the [idiomatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom) way to do it.

Note also that the command-line options supported by `cat` and `tee` are different.  You would probably expect this, since they mostly do different things, and thus are capable of having their behavior customized in totally different way. See [`man cat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cat.1.html) and [`man tee`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/tee.1.html) for details, especially about this.

Comment: So for my use case I want to just create a EML file and therefore cat is the most suited method right? Since tee will do more than create an EML file?

Comment: @Peter Either will work in your use case, as you're not passing filenames to `tee` or `cat`, so they both copy standard input to standard output (and you're not passing options to them either, which they might interpret differently if you did). The commands you showed really *do* do the same thing. I suggest you use `cat`, though, because that's what people usually do in this situation. ```/home/cam/Documents/TestEmails/`date '+%Y-%m-%d - %H-%M-%S'`.eml``` isn't passed to `tee` or `cat` as a command-line argument; instead, due to `>`, the shell redirects standard output to the file it names.

Comment: Will cat be likely to not get depicted and not change in how it functions in the years to come?

Comment: @Peter When run with no command-line arguments (no filename arguments and no option arguments), the behavior of `cat` and `tee` is unlikely ever to change in a way relevant to the distinction between them. As far as they are depicted, though, yes: you are less likely to see guides recommending `tee` for this purpose than `cat`. Using `tee` without passing filenames to it is fairly strange. It's fine, though. If for some reason you prefer it, you can go ahead. Just remember that if you do ever add filename arguments, it will write to them rather than reading from them as `cat` would.

Answer (score 0):

In summary `cat` is for reading (*manual input* and *files*) and writing (with `>` and `>>`) to files. And `tee` is only about writing to files - but in **simultaneously** according to the output of the command that is serving how its input.

For example:

- `ping 192.168.1.xx | tee [-a] ping_report.txt`

With the command shown above you can **simultaneously** see the output of the `ping` command **and** that output be writing in the `ping_report.txt` file (to be analyzed later of course). If the `-a` parameter is used, then the input (output of the first command) is appended to the `ping_report.txt` file, otherwise it overrides current content by the new input.